# Actionscript: How to set an Image/Icon to a DisplayObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, ria

Now there is a Constructor: **MyMarker(icon:DisplayObject=null)** which accepts any DisplayObject, if I create a new instance of MyMarker(just new MyMarker()),it will be dsplayed with a default Icon,so how to set a Image/Icon into this Constructor? Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: You really need to give more information. You should give the code of `MyMarker`, and tell us what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a not open-source API,I want to know if a image can be set into a DisplayObject or any sub of DisplayObject can draw an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an appropriate DisplayObject in advance and then pass the reference to this object in the constructor:

```
var myLittleCustomIcon:Sprite = new Sprite();
myLittleCustomIcon.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
myLittleCustomIcon.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
myLittleCustomIcon.graphics.endFill();
var myCustomMaker:MyMarker = new MyMarker(myLittleCustomIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to tell from your question but, if you want to set a default icon if NO DisplayObject is passed, just check if icon is null in the MyMarker constructor, eg:

```
...
public function MyMarker(icon:DisplayObject=null) {
    if (icon==null) {
    // set default icon here...

    }

    }
...
```

As for the inheritance issue, so long as the object passed inherits from DisplayObject, you should be fine. You may run into trouble if you try to invoke methods on the object that don't appear in DisplayObject.